# Which DAG would explain the lack of correlation between height and performance in NBA players?

Tags: causality, graphical-model, dag, selection-bias

A classic example of "selection bias" involves looking at the performance of professional basketball players. The example goes, among NBA players there is no correlation between height and performance.
Obviously that cannot be generalized to "height has no relationship with being good at basketball for all players", it is just that by the time you are selected to play for the NBA, other features are more important.

What I can't seem to do is to explain this through a DAG. I've come up more or less with this structure:

[image]

But it seems clear to me that here fixing the value "Plays for NBA" to TRUE would not make height independent from performance.  Does it mean that the structure of the DAG is wrong? Or is there a better way to show this kind of selection bias?

Comment: What's the difference between Playing Skill and Performance?

Comment: ah, yes! Performance is observable (say,  points scored per game) , skill is not

Comment: Why not just make it $$\text{player height} \leftarrow \text{plays for NBA} \rightarrow \text{performance}$$ this way, given that someone plays for the NBA, their height is independent from their performance. I am guessing this is what you mean by "The example goes, among NBA players there is no correlation between height and performance."

Answer (score 1):

You could make “plays in the NBA” a moderator in your model, but that seems to be a very bad model of the world. The simplest model is that height predicts performance, but you need more variables when you want to predict performance at the extreme tails.

I could be wrong about this next point, but I think DAGs should capture an underlying model of the world, rather than be treated as a decision tree

Comment: Welcome to CV! This answer seems to provide only a vague answer to the question. It may be better to provide some specifics using DAGs.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/359912)